# Collectionview coverflow speed

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, coverflow

I am using github library for coverflow in my application

https://github.com/schwa/Coverflow

Is there any way to reduce scrolling speed of collection view so that only one cell will be moved left or right at a time?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to set the UICollectionViews decelartionRate property to UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast:

```
    self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

This will slow down the scroll, unless the user does a high velocity swipe it will stop at each cell.  I am not using that specific library but I have created a custom cover flow layout where I am using the decelerationRate property to accomplish this and it works fine.